# Losing custom headers on HTTP 500

Tags: .net, iis-7, .net-4.0, global-asax

As part of `Global.asax`'s `BeginRequest` event I conditionally add a CORS header based on a web.config value.

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```

I lose this header when an HTTP 500 occurs. I've stepped through my code and the current response still maintains the headers throughout the `Error` event. Is there something else I can override that is flushing this headers?

**Edit:** The EndRequest event shows that the custom headers are missing and it looks like I can add them there instead. will update after

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure exactly what happens during the process but adding an event to `EndRequest` and checking for 500 allowed me to successfully add the headers back in.